# A fantasy story about a king who forgets everything after drinking the incorrect potion

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short fantasy story that I read in the early 1980s. Because of the story's not child-friendly nature, I am almost sure I did read it in a young adult fantasy book with no illustrations and probably as a part of a collection of similar stories. Sadly, I don't remember the title or the cover of the book. The story is about a king who lived with his queen in a remote kingdom. The queen was his true love, and he couldn't fathom his existence without her. I remember the queen falling and dying while out riding her horse. The king was heartbroken and couldn't stand the prospect of life without her.

Desperate to bring her back to life, the king sought out a wizard (or an alchemist) who was known for his magical abilities. The wizard told the king that he didn't have a resurrection-potion that could bring the queen back to life but that he had a potion that could make the king forget about her. The king was initially hesitant, but eventually consented to drink the potion from a chalice. The magician, who was very old and almost blind, made a mistake and gave the king a potion that made him forget, not only the queen but about everything else in his life, including his kingdom and his people. The last thing I remember from the story is the wizard scooping up the king's crown and mantle off the floor and putting them on.

Comment: *"Funny you say that. After a lot of hard work, 
Robby gave the king a magic gold coin. This coin  gave the king the ability to remember only the  good times Robert had with his daughter the  lovely princess." I reached into my jeans pocket  and pulled out a yellow aluminum token. "King  Robert never drank the toxic potion again."  I handed the light shinny coin to Suzie-Lee. 
She rolled it over in her small tan hands. 
"Is this the magic coin?" 
"No," I laughed a little, "but it looks like the 
coin. It helps with my story."* - Suzie-Lee and the Story.

Comment: I don’t understand this comment at all. Sorry, maybe I’m being a bit thick! 